# Calculating resistance with a multimeter

Tags: resistance, multimeter

I recently took on the job of working on someone's amplifier. There was a burnt smell coming from it. I found the pieces of the puzzle that were fried and replaced the ones I could, two diodes and two resistors. There's a third resistor, however, that was completely blackened. I can't read the color code so I can't tell what resistance is it. I haven't used a multimeter since high school because I primarily only work on guitars and they're simple enough to work on without one. Can someone walk me through the steps of calculating the resistance so I can order the part and get this amp back to the customer? Thanks.

Comment: Normally you would measure the voltage across it and the current through it. However, it's blackened ... there's no guarantee that the resistance you measure won't be affected by whatever blackened the resistor in the first place. That is to say, the resistor is cooked - don't expect that it's the same value it was prior to cooking.

Comment: Sorry, but if it's fried then the resistance likely won't be correct anymore.  Are there other, similar, circuits on the PCB to look at for clues?  Can you find a schematic?

Comment: Well - *normally*  you would just switch the multimeter to a resistance setting and measure it - no calculation required. But as others have already pointed out, that measurement is probably not reliable.

Comment: There are no schematics anywhere unfortunately. The amp was built by a fairly unreputably company and I believe it's no longer in production. Guitar Research T64RS Tube is the model if anyone knows anything, the resistor number is R67

Comment: Also, I looked up how to use the meter and the resistor itself came up as a 2.2k ohm. However, that's most likely not accurate. The thing is fried like a marshmallow. From examination, it also appears to be the only 1 watt resistor on the circuit board. There's a handful of 2 watts, and the rest are 1/2

Comment: You either have to know the gain of the circuit (what it does) or know the value. Either that or contact the company and see if they can tell you.

Comment: You can't measure a broken resistor with confidence.  Ask someplace like http://music-electronics-forum.com/ to see if anyone can give you a value for R67.  Be sure to replace it with one that can handle enough power.

Answer (score 3):

I did a search for Guitar Research T64RS and found a reference to it here: http://music-electronics-forum.com/t38041/. The poster was asking about the type of mains transformer, but he had very conveniently attached a good enough photo of the circuit board. It should be easy to determine if this is the same board as yours. If you zoom in you can see R67 about halfway down the photo. To me it appears to have the color code BROWN-BROWN-BROWN-GOLD which is 110 Ohms 5%.

[image]

Comment: Nice, Steve, that was well done :)  My eyes are sees that resistor as brown-black-black-gold, though, which is 10 Ohm 5%.   Anybody feel like weighing in?  (@MikeMills)

Comment: @bitsmack always a problem with color monitors! I'm 99% sure its brown-brown-brown-gold. Does anyone have a calibrated monitor?

Comment: I'm on a laptop, so my screen _is_ suspect :)

Comment: Old post, but maybe still useful to someone else: the color looks NOT brown-brown-brown-gold because the first band isn't as dark as the second two, so I'd agree more with "black brown brown gold". Also possible it's "red brown brown gold" for the same shading reasons. BUT I've discovered, black for a 1st band doesn't seem to be a thing? That's according to SparkFun's docs.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth because this is an old post, but the value is 10 ohms. The colors are brown-black-black-gold. I replaced it preventively after reading this post and seeing on the PCB it had become hot, however the resistor was still functional in mine. My problem had to do with zener ZR6, which was fried.